# os.chdir returns No such file or directory: 'None'

Tags: python, string, directory, chdir

How come that these lines of code creates a folder, but returns an error output?

```
key_ = "Test"
new_folder = os.makedirs(str(key_)+str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')))
os.chdir(str(new_folder))
```

[image: Folder]

The error I'm getting is

```
line 457, in download_url
os.chdir(str(new_folder))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'None'
```

Comment: I'd advise not to put '/' or '\' in file or directory names as moving between Windows & Unix, it will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the solution:

```
file_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
output_files = file_path.replace('billede_indsamling.py',str(output_dir))
os.chdir(output_files)
new_folder = str(key_)+str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
#os.mkdir(new_folder) 
path = os.path.join(output_files, new_folder)

if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)
    print("Directory '%s' created successfully" %new_folder)
elif os.path.exists(path):
    os.chdir(path)
```

Answer (score 2):

`os.makedirs()` doesn't return the name of the directory it created. Assign the directory name to a variable first, and use that in both function calls.

```
key_ = "Test"
new_folder = str(key_)+str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
os.makedirs(new_folder, exist_ok=True)
os.chdir(new_folder)
```

Comment: I still be getting an error saying   -------->  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'Test2022-07-25 21:41:55'

Comment: Use the `exist_ok = True` option to prevent errors if the directory already exists.